# Using python AWS sdk (boto3), how to decrypt an email that was saved by ses

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-ses

My setup is this: using AWS, I have an SES rule that saves incoming emails on an s3 bucket with encryption. When I am using java sdk to read, its read with no problem ,using this [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/client-side-using-kms-java.html)

When trying to read it using the AWS python api, I keep getting `InvalidCiphertextException`. This is my python program:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3_resource('s3')
kms = boto3_client('kms')
obj = s3.Object('my_bucket_name', 'my_object_key').get()

body=obj['Body'].read()

t = kms.decrypt(
    CiphertextBlob=blob,
    EncryptionContext ={

        "aws:ses:message-id" : "<my_message_id>",
        "aws:ses:source-account" : "<my_account-number>",
        "kms_cmk_id" : "<kms_cmk_id>",
        "aws:ses:rule-name" : "<my_ses_rule>"
    }
)
print t['Plaintext']
```

here is the stack trace:

```
 - File "C:\Users\yigal\git\receipt-email-archive-api\playground.py", line 101, in read_encrypted2
    "aws:ses:rule-name" : "VERIFONE_rule"
 - File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 253, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
 - File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 557, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
 - InvalidCiphertextException: An error occurred (InvalidCiphertextException) when calling the Decrypt operation:
```

Comment: Can you post the exception trace?

Comment: Hi @yigal, did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: @Richard . I did not. I ended up writing a java service just to retrieve the decrypted messages from s3. The main python program uses that service via Rest API

Comment: Alas, I dug a little deeper on this, basically, if you encrypt an SES email and move it to s3, s3 will not decrypt your email when you do a get_object. You therefore need to get the encryption key from AWS KMS, and decrypt the email locally. Thanks @yigal

Answer (score 0):

Your variable "blob" is null because the variable you read into was called "body"

Comment: You may consider to post such short diagnostics in a comment. Answers are meant to post a complete solution with explanation.